# How to remove the 6th character from a string for two different letters using SUBSTR( ) function

Tags: mysql, substring

I am using a SUBSTR( ) function to filter out data having a particular 6th character.
Eg -
substr(string,6,1) <> 'I'
so if there are two strings ABCDFGB and CVBYHIZ, then CVBYHIZ will be filtered out from my search.

OUTPUT - ABCDFGB

I am not able to figure out proper operation query to filter out string having 'I' and 'G' as the 6th character at the same time.
Can someone help?

Comment: `WHERE SUBSTR(column, 6, 1) NOT IN ('I', 'G')`

Comment: thank you. It seems to be working

Comment: There is one issue - this condition also ejects rows where the column is NULL...

Comment: yeah...right..just observed that. :(

Comment: If NULL rows must be returned use `WHERE SUBSTR(column, 6, 1) NOT IN ('I', 'G') OR column IS NULL` or `WHERE COALESCE(SUBSTR(column, 6, 1), '') NOT IN ('I', 'G')`.

Comment: i am using the first option, as we are fetching data only for the rows which has data and we are not looking for rows with NULL. So the first query is good.